# SQL loader control file condition to format the data

Tags: sql-loader

Because of the "-" in the END_DATE column in the source file data is not getting inserted in to the table.

I want this to work as in the below condition.

```
IF '-' UPDATE END_DATE = NULL
ELSE END_DATE DATE "DD-MM-YYYY"
```

Control file:

```
infile 'Test.csv'
append into table DATA.Test
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
(
  EMPLOYEE_ID
  END_DATE DATE "DD-MM-YYYY"
)
```

Source Data: Test.csv

```
EMPLOYEE_ID,END_DATE DATE
"12345","-"  
"12346","12/11/2016"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement in the control file like this:

```
infile 'Test.csv'
append into table DATA.Test
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
(
EMPLOYEE_ID,
END_DATE DATE "CASE WHEN :END_DATE = '-' THEN NULL 
                    ELSE to_date(:END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
               END"
)
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, It worked with minor changes to the syntax,                                                   END_DATE  "CASE WHEN :END_DATE = '-' THEN NULL 
                    ELSE to_date(:END_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
               END"